# Characters not displaying after space form MySQL resultset

Tags: php, mysql, textbox

I am a fresher in PHP, I am trying to create a form which will be auto filled from the MySQL database. The form is getting created, and populated from the database data. **But, in case the data contains a space in between, the characters after the space are not getting displayed.**

**The php page:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

 // Check if we have parameters employeeId being passed to the script through the URL
   if (isset($_GET["employeeId"])) {

      $employeeId = $_GET["employeeId"];

     //=============Data Display=================
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","employee_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  `employee_id` ,  `employee_name` ,  `employee_email` ,  `employee_mobile` ,  `employee_address` 
FROM  `employee_details` 
WHERE  `employee_id` =$employeeId");

echo "<h2>Edit Employee</h2><br/>
<form name='myForm' action='' onSubmit='return validateForm()' method='post'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "Employee Id: ". $row['employee_id'] ."<br/>";
 echo "Employee Name: <input type='text' name='EmployeeName' value=". $row['employee_name'] ."><br/>"; 
 echo "Employee Email: <input type='text' name='EmployeeEmail' value=". $row['employee_email'] ."><br/>"; 
 echo "Employee Mobile: <input type='text' name='EmployeeMobile' value=". $row['employee_mobile'] ."><br/>"; 
 echo "Employee Address: <Input type='text' name = 'product_name5' value=".$row['employee_address']."><br/>"; 
  }


mysqli_close($con);

//=============Data Display=================
   }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Where am I going wrong? What should I do to get all the data including spaces in the textboxes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Value` attribute of inputs should be with quotes too:

```
value='" . $value . "'
```

In your case:

```
echo "Employee Name: <input type='text' name='EmployeeName' value='". $row['employee_name'] ."'><br/>";
echo "Employee Email: <input type='text' name='EmployeeEmail' value='". $row['employee_email'] ."'><br/>"; 
echo "Employee Mobile: <input type='text' name='EmployeeMobile' value='". $row['employee_mobile'] ."'><br/>"; 
echo "Employee Address: <Input type='text' name = 'product_name5' value='".$row['employee_address']."'><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create link fetch from database like download link
use this type code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    //echo $ip."<br />";REGEXP
    //echo $name."<br />";
    echo "<table border=2px style='border-radius=20px;' align=center><tr>
    <th>Document ID</th>
    <th>Document Name Type</th>
    <th>Download Documents</th>
    </tr>";//<th>Project Document Type</th>
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $path1=$row['FOLDERNAME'] .'/'. $row['FILENAME'] .'.'. $row['DOCTYPE'];
        $path=str_replace(" ", '%20', $path1);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DocID'] . "</td>";
       // echo "<td>" . $row['PROJDOCTYPE'] . "</td>";Thank you. Your Apple ID is now ready for use.
        echo "<td>" . $row['DOCNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><a href=Tender/'.$path.'>'.$row['DOCNAME'].'</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```